# git hangs my terminal

Tags: git, terminal

I keep getting hung in the terminal. 
I finally located where the problem was because of git.

1. I remove the git version control by removing the whole .git folder, then the terminal works fine.
2. I found that there was always a `git ls-files` running process when the terminal hung.

the project structure:

`├── data
│   ├── DRIVE
│   │   ├── patch_train_neg
│   │   ├── patch_train_pos
│   │   ├── test
│   │   ├── train
│   │   └── train.txt
├── run_prepare_data.py
├── .git
└── run_prepare_txt.py`

I do like to use git for *.py files in that folder. However, there are 100k small files in patch_train_pos and patch_train_neg.

what can I do to stop terminal hanging by git?

Comment: Well, what's running `git ls-files`?

Comment: Have you add some git plugin for your terminal? In that case, the plugin may check if there is different between local and remote git repos. I encountered such problem when using Posh-git for PowerShell, the terminal becomes laggy when opening git repo folders.

Comment: I am running a bash shell, I think git is automatically monitor my project because I am under version control.

Comment: yes, I just start trying git lfs (large file support)

Comment: Git isn't a service, it doesn't monitor anything.  (Not sure about Git LFS, but imagine it's the same.)